# Reassigning a passed by reference variable to a different type

Tags: python, reference

I don't quite understand when python passes/copies variables by value, reference.

In this example, it seems `arg` is passed by reference, and a reference is held within the `MyClass` instance, so when `func` modifies `self.val` it also modifies `arg`.

```
arg = [1,2,3]
class MyClass:
  def func(self, arg):
    self.val = arg
    self.val[0] = -22

m = MyClass()
m.func(arg)
print(arg)
```

prints

```
[-22, 2, 3]
```

In this case, it seems `self.val` gets overwritten by the `-22`, and nothing seems to happen to `arg`. So in this case, why does `arg` not become modified? Why is the list not changed to an int?

```
arg = [1,2,3]
class MyClass:
  def func(self, arg):
    self.val = arg
    self.val = -22

m = MyClass()
m.func(arg)
print(arg)
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: In the second example, you've overwritten `self.val` to be the literal value `-22`. This doesn't change the object that was previously stored in `self.val` - it's storing a new value instead. Therefore, changes are not reflected on the external list object. Otherwise, lists in Python are mutable and therefore they are passed by _object reference_, which is why changes in the first example modify the global `arg` variable.

Comment: Python passes arguments 'by assignment'. Here is a good review of what that means [link](https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/). The practical effect depends on whether the object is mutable or not.

Comment: This is a useful explanation of the concepts: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html Particularly, the section under *"Fact: References can be more than just names"* talks about the behaviour of assigning to list elements, which is what you are doing here.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, you seem to expect changes to `self.val` to be reflected to the object passed as an argument. This is not the case. Consider the following simple example.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
b = 123

print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
123
```

In the above, `b = a` causes variable `b` to reference the same object as variable `a`. However, the following line `b = 123` causes `b` to reference a new piece of data altogether. As you can see by the output, this does not change the value of `a`.

This is precisely what is happening in your second example. You may be confused because you are expecting the list object to be *passed by reference*. It is not, it is *passed by object reference* which is a subtle distinction. You don't pass a pointer to the data as you might do in a language such as C/C++.

More specifically, Python allows for passing by value and passing by *object reference*. Immutable types in Python are passed by value, and thus changes within a function will not reflect on the external object. Mutable types, however, are passed by *object reference*, which is why you notice the changes to the global `args` list object in your first example. In Python a list is a mutable type.

Comment: Immutable types, even "primitives", are also passed by object reference. A demonstration of this for ints: https://ideone.com/I7H6dW. However, for most purposes, immutables can be mentally modelled as if they were passed by value, since the function they are passed to can't mutate them.